# rails routing; path changing for collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

At the moment my route for other_notifications/chat_notificaitons is:

```
/users/:id/notifications/chat_notifications
```

but I 'd like to have it like:

```
/users/1/chat_notifications
```

How can I do that? Is there any issue to watch out for if I change the routes like this?

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  resources :notifications, only: [:create, :index] do
    collection do
      get :other_notifications, :chat_notifications
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :notifications, only: [:create, :index] 
end
get 'users/:user_id/chat_notifications', to: 'controllerName#actionName', as: :custom_name
```

Comment: Yang, after the # comes the controller name, right?

Comment: Here is the rule: `controllerName#actionName`

Comment: how you define the path with it?

Comment: Please see my updates to add a path `custom_name_path`

Comment: Yang, I tried a custom one :), it didn't work out. I'm asking because user id has to be passed. Can you send me the exact code? What I'm trying to achive is to have everything including path/action name etc. as it was except the url name.

Comment: I am confused now. Please update your question with the related code, like your controller or view and point out where you have problems.

Comment: Yang, based on what I like to do how you would exactly modify my code? Could you write someting like as: chat_notifications_user_notifications rather than as: custom_name? The problem is that it doesn't find the user which is necessary since the route is nested.

Comment: The path name is whatever you can change, there is no problem to change it to `as: :chat_notifications_user_notifications`. If your code cannot find the user, the problem is the parameter `params[:id]` is not get recognized.

Comment: I will check it out. This param problem is weird since if I leave it as it is now, everything is working fine.

Comment: It's working with get 'users/:user_id/...... Yang, plz modify your answer for other who may see this post.